# RestSharp removing dot from body

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-web-api2, restsharp

I'm using restsharp to perform a POST request to my endpoint.

When I add the body, I do this:

```
request.AddParameter("text/json", message, ParameterType.RequestBody);
```

The string message is done in this way: **VALUE1.VALUE2**
It is really simple.

But my endpoint receives only **VALUE1**

The endpoint signature is:

```
[HttpPost]
public HttpResponseMessage DoJob([FromBody] string id)
```

Do you know why? Do I have to encode somehow the message I'm sending?

Doing the same with postman for test purpose I'm not experiencing this behavior.

Thanks!

Comment: How do you get params in endpoint? Or can you add endpoint definition and url?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem passing the body in another way.

Instead of:

```
request.AddParameter("text/json", message, ParameterType.RequestBody);
```

I put:

```
request.RequestFormat = DataFormat.Json;
request.AddBody(message);
```

Now whatever character is inside the message, the message content (as long as it is json) is properly passed to my endpoint

Comment: Why you didn't accept it when I posted it first time?)

Comment: @Chase: because I understood later that this was the right answer :)

Comment: Why you change your opinion again, it's funny?) BTW, your current solution, in this post, didn't work, because your definition of API is waiting for id parameter and you didn't define it, so your id in action always be null. But you set it like answer. You are funny guy)

Comment: @Chase: actually is working. I didn't understand the comment you did about id parameter

Answer (score 1):

Here is my working example for `RestSharp` version 105.1.0.0:

```
var message = "VALUE1.VALUE2"
var client = new RestClient("http://localhost:64648"); //replace with your domain name
var request = new RestRequest("/Home/DoJob", Method.POST); //replace 'Home' with your controller name
request.RequestFormat = DataFormat.Json;
request.AddBody(new { id = message });
client.Execute(request);
```

And my endpoint definition

```
[HttpPost]
public HttpResponseMessage DoJob([System.Web.Http.FromBody] string id) {
  //some code
}
```

Everything is working as expected.

BTW, if you want post array you need change only two places:

```
request.AddBody(new { ids = message.Split('.') });
```

And definition

```
[HttpPost]
public HttpResponseMessage DoJob([System.Web.Http.FromBody] string[] ids) {
  //some code
}
```